# ionic build android failure :Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: ionic-framework

```
D:\myApp>ionic run android
Running command: D:\environment\nodejs\node.exe D:\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\myApp


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=D:\environment\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=D:\environment\Java\jdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE


:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: ����: �Ҳ�������

import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;

                     ^

  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest

  λ��: ������ android.webkit

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: ����: �Ҳ�������
    private final ClientCertRequest request;

                  ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� CordovaClientCertRequest
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: ����: �Ҳ������
�

    public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {

                                    ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� CordovaClientCertRequest


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:40: ����: �Ҳ�������

import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
                     ^
  ����:   �� PermissionRequest
  λ��: ������ android.webkit

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:264: ����: �Ҳ�������

    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                                                                                                                         ^
  ����:   �� FileChooserParams
  λ��: �� WebChromeClient

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:284: ����: �Ҳ�������
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                                          ^

  ����:   �� PermissionRequest

  λ��: �� SystemWebChromeClient

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:29: ����: �Ҳ������
�

import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^

  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: ������ android.webkit


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:116: ����: �Ҳ������
�

    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
                                                           ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� SystemWebViewClient


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:35: ����: �Ҳ������
�
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:262: ����: �Ҳ�������

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)


                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:282: ����: �Ҳ�������

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:226: ����: �Ҳ�������

        getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, mappedRequestCode);
                     ^
  ����:   ���� requestPermissions(String[],int)

  λ��: �� Activity

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:231: ����: �Ҳ�������

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                       ^
  ����:   ���� M
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:233: ����: �Ҳ�������

            int result = activity.checkSelfPermission(permission);
                                 ^
  ����:   ���� checkSelfPermission(String)

  λ��: ����ΪActivity�ı��� activity

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaActivity.java:503: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���

    @Override
    ^

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:43: ����: �Ҳ������
�

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {


                                                        ^

  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:44: ����: �Ҳ�������
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                         ^
  ����:   ���� setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView,boolean)
  λ��: ����ΪCookieManager�ı��� cookieManager


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:65: ����: �Ҳ�������

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:66: ����: �Ҳ�������
            cookieManager.flush();
                         ^

  ����:   ���� flush()
  λ��: ����ΪCookieManager�ı��� cookieManager

D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:263: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���


    @Override

    ^


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:270: ����: �Ҳ������
�

                    Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                                                  ^
  ����:   ���� FileChooserParams
  λ��: �� WebChromeClient


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:283: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���

    @Override

    ^


D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:114: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ� ֳ����͵ķ���


    @Override


    ^

ע: ĳЩ�����ļ�ʹ�û�����ѹ�ʱ�� API��


ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣


23 ������

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


>
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


* Try:

Run with


--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 4.324 secs


Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: ����: �Ҳ�������
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: ������ android.webkit
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: ����: �Ҳ�������
    private final ClientCertRequest request;
                  ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� CordovaClientCertRequest
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: ����: �Ҳ�������
    public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {
                                    ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� CordovaClientCertRequest
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:40: ����: �Ҳ�������
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
                     ^
  ����:   �� PermissionRequest
  λ��: ������ android.webkit
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:264: ����: �Ҳ�������
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                                                                                                                         ^
  ����:   �� FileChooserParams
  λ��: �� WebChromeClient
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:284: ����: �Ҳ�������
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                                          ^
  ����:   �� PermissionRequest
  λ��: �� SystemWebChromeClient
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:29: ����: �Ҳ�������
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: ������ android.webkit
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:116: ����: �Ҳ�������
    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
                                                           ^
  ����:   �� ClientCertRequest
  λ��: �� SystemWebViewClient
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:35: ����: �Ҳ�������
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:262: ����: �Ҳ�������
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:282: ����: �Ҳ�������
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                  ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:226: ����: �Ҳ�������
        getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, mappedRequestCode);
                     ^
  ����:   ���� requestPermissions(String[],int)
  λ��: �� Activity
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:231: ����: �Ҳ�������
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                       ^
  ����:   ���� M
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:233: ����: �Ҳ�������
            int result = activity.checkSelfPermission(permission);
                                 ^
  ����:   ���� checkSelfPermission(String)
  λ��: ����ΪActivity�ı��� activity
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaActivity.java:503: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���
    @Override
    ^
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:43: ����: �Ҳ�������
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:44: ����: �Ҳ�������
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                         ^
  ����:   ���� setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView,boolean)
  λ��: ����ΪCookieManager�ı��� cookieManager
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:65: ����: �Ҳ�������
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                        ^
  ����:   ���� LOLLIPOP
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java:66: ����: �Ҳ�������
            cookieManager.flush();
                         ^
  ����:   ���� flush()
  λ��: ����ΪCookieManager�ı��� cookieManager
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:263: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���
    @Override
    ^
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:270: ����: �Ҳ�������
                    Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                                                  ^
  ����:   ���� FileChooserParams
  λ��: �� WebChromeClient
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebChromeClient.java:283: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ�ֳ����͵ķ���
    @Override
    ^
D:\myApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java:114: ����: �������Ḳ�ǻ�ʵ� ֳ����͵ķ���
    @Override
    ^
ע: ĳЩ�����ļ�ʹ�û�����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
23 ������

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



D:\myApp>
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting (Ctrl+K), otherwise your post will appear as normal text instead of code.

Answer (score 8):

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova prepare android
ionic cordova build android
```

This will work for modern versions of Ionic CLI. If it doesn't work, try downloading the latest version.

Comment: this did not worked for me. same error keeps repeating

Answer (score 4):

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
ionic cordova prepare android
ionic cordova build android
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding these 2 plugins

> "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
>
> "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {}

Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
ionic platform remove android

ionic platform add android@6.3.0
```

I hope this may help

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me. in this order

ionic platform remove android

ionic platform add android

ionic prepare android

ionic build android

Answer (score 0):

This must be that two plugin you've installed are incompatible. I'm facing this issue with local-notifications. I managed it by downgrading its version to one which was compatible with the rest of the plugins.

Check out which plugin is causing you problems by the command

```
ionic cordova plugin list
```

and building when you removed the incompatible plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
ionic cordova prepare android
ionic cordova build android
```

It just worked for me because of the 6.3.0 version definition, if you tried without it, you may try with it

Answer (score 0):

Trying to check on your project the below dependencies

1. `ionic cordova platform remove android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0`
3. `ionic cordova prepare android`
4. `ionic cordova build android`